# qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ' '

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, qmake

I checked others similar questions, but still didn't understand what I need to do.
I have compiled qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1 library and installed in /home/usr/install/Qt, using --prefix.
Everything was fine.
But I don't understand how can I use my installed qt library now?
For example: I have test project and .pro file. I want to do something like this: 'qmake test.pro' and get the makefile.
But

> qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

What should I do?

Note: I need to install the library only in my home folder.
Note2: It's work fine if I run qmake with full path e.g:

> ~/install/Qt/bin/qmake test.pro

Also, I added in the PATH variable path to my Qt/bin. But if I just write 'qmake ...' without full path to qmake, I have mentioned problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. That is how Unix works. You can only execute binaries with their names in the PATH. You can double check with `which` if they are found, or even `locate`.

If you use the full path, then it is all clear for the interpreter for sure. I would suggest to do something in your bash, zsh or etc. profile:

```
PATH=~/install/Qt/bin/:$PATH
```

Alternatively, you can just do it manually in a separate session and work with Qt in there.

You could also create an alias for the full path if you wish, but that would be a stranger solution.

Of course, the best would be to install it system-wide, and once your distribution gets it packaged, just use your package manager.

Comment: It's work! I should add my path in the beginning and not the end of $PATH. Thank you :)